# Need advice on creating an online contract generation system

Tags: system

First  of all, be assured I am not asking how to write up a contract; I already have that covered.  My question is how I can best program a system for generating it for clients to digitally sign?

My original plan that just seems like overkill to me is this:

1. I fill in all the details.
2. Click a button to preview it, making sure everything is correct.
3. Click a button to simultaneously create a directory for the client and create 3 files inside that directory.

The three newly created files are:

1. the unsigned contract.
2. a confirmation page of having signed the contract, with other details the client will need to know.
3. the actual signed contract that the client can now view online at any time by going to a URL such as /clients/username/index.php

I have it working, though I keep thinking it could be simplified further, but not sure of the best way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently helped on a project much like this, & I think you've got the right idea...

1. Write up the contract & preview (make sure it's right)
2. Have them come "sign" it
3. Save it

Only thing I'd change is, I'd use a DB instead of file creation. Personally, I find that simpler, but it might not feel that way to everybody. It's definitely more flexible though, 'cause you can easily generate an HTML or a PDF from the DB data, but you'd have a harder time doing that from a file on the system. Assuming you're using PHP (based on the .php you mentioned), there's a whole section of functions for generating [PDF's in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php).